# nginx yii2 tips 500 Internal Server Error when getenforce is enforcing

Tags: nginx, yii2, selinux

I copied my site to Google Platform, it tips `500 Internal Server Error` (eg when I visit this page https://letsclassifieds.com/info/add ),But it runs ok on vultr and other services.

### Directory /htdocs/flxx/basic/runtime is in mod 0777

```
[root@instance-1 ~]# ll / | grep htdocs
drwxr-xr-x.   6 www  apache   55 Apr 24 01:53 htdocs
[root@instance-1 ~]# ll /htdocs/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  3 www apache   18 Apr 24 05:16 flxx
drwxr-xr-x.  7 www apache   78 Apr 24 03:03 phpbids
drwxr-xr-x. 12 www apache 4096 Apr 24 04:05 pma
drwxr-xr-x.  3 www apache   39 Apr 24 05:20 uploads
[root@instance-1 ~]# ll /htdocs/flxx/
total 4
drw-r--r--. 23 www apache 4096 Apr 24 06:44 basic
[root@instance-1 ~]# ll /htdocs/flxx/basic/
total 196
drw-r--r--.  2 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:39 actions
drw-r--r--.  2 www apache     25 Apr 24 06:39 assets
drw-r--r--.  4 www apache     80 Apr 24 06:41 commands
drw-r--r--.  5 www apache     44 Apr 24 06:39 components
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache   1806 Apr 24 06:41 composer.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache 124826 Apr 24 06:44 composer.lock
drw-r--r--.  6 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:58 config
drw-r--r--.  5 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:41 controllers
drw-r--r--.  4 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:41 document
drw-r--r--.  2 www apache     28 Apr 24 06:41 events
drw-r--r--.  4 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:41 helpers
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache   1622 Apr 24 06:39 LICENSE.md
drw-r--r--.  9 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:39 mail
drw-r--r--.  3 www apache     18 Apr 24 06:39 messages
drw-r--r--.  3 www apache     89 Apr 24 06:41 migrations
drw-r--r--. 11 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:39 models
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache   2699 Apr 24 06:39 README.md
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache   5049 Apr 24 06:39 requirements.php
drwxrwxrwx.  3 www apache     49 Apr 24 08:19 runtime
drw-r--r--.  2 www apache     42 Apr 24 06:41 shell
drw-r--r--.  3 www apache     62 Apr 24 06:39 tests
drw-r--r--.  2 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:41 validators
drw-r--r--. 27 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:44 vendor
drw-r--r--. 22 www apache   4096 Apr 24 06:39 views
drw-r--r--.  9 www apache   4096 Apr 24 07:01 web
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache    697 Apr 24 06:39 yii
-rw-r--r--.  1 www apache    515 Apr 24 06:39 yii.bat
[root@instance-1 ~]#
```

### php-fpm error log

```
# /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log

Previous exception:
yii\base\InvalidConfigException: The directory is not writable by the Web process: /htdocs/flxx/basic/web/assets in /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:215
Stack trace:
#0 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\web\AssetManager->init()
#1 [internal function]: yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#2 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(375): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#3 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\web\\AssetMa...', Array, Array)
#4 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(344): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\web\\AssetMa...', Array, Array)
#5 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(135): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#6 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(605): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('assetManager')
#7 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(225): yii\base\Application->getAssetManager()
#8 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(285): yii\web\View->getAssetManager()
#9 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(125): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('yii\\bootstrap\\B...')
#10 /htdocs/flxx/basic/views/layouts/main.php(14): yii\web\AssetBundle::register(Object(yii\web\View))
#11 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(328): require('/htdocs/flxx/ba...')
#12 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/htdocs/flxx/ba...', Array)
#13 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(396): yii\base\View->renderFile('/htdocs/flxx/ba...', Array, Object(app\controllers\InfoController))
#14 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(382): yii\base\Controller->renderContent('<div class="row...')
#15 /htdocs/flxx/basic/actions/InfoListAction.php(158): yii\base\Controller->render('list', Array)
#16 [internal function]: app\actions\InfoListAction->run('area', '1', '107', '0')
#17 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Action.php(94): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(156): yii\base\Action->runWithParams(Array)
#19 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('list', Array)
#20 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('info/list', Array)
#21 /htdocs/flxx/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#22 /htdocs/flxx/basic/web/index.php(16): yii\base\Application->run()
#23 {main}
$_SERVER = [
    'USER' => 'apache',
    'HOME' => '/usr/share/httpd',
    'HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE' => 'Fri, 14 Apr 2017 09:33:39 GMT',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip,deflate,br',
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
    'HTTP_FROM' => 'googlebot(at)googlebot.com',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'Keep-alive',
```

### nginx error log

```
# /var/log/nginx/error.log

2017/04/24 09:47:41 [crit] 12139#0: *1 stat() "/htdocs/flxx/basic/web/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/add HTTP/1.1", host: "let
sclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
2017/04/24 09:47:41 [crit] 12139#0: *1 stat() "/htdocs/flxx/basic/web/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/add HTTP/1.1", host: "let
sclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
2017/04/24 09:47:41 [crit] 12139#0: *1 stat() "/htdocs/flxx/basic/web/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/add HTTP/1.1", host: "let
sclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
2017/04/24 09:47:41 [crit] 12139#0: *1 stat() "/htdocs/flxx/basic/web/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/add HTTP/1.1", host: "let
sclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
2017/04/24 09:47:41 [crit] 12139#0: *1 stat() "/htdocs/flxx/basic/web/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/add HTTP/1.1", host: "let
sclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
2017/04/24 09:47:41 [error] 12139#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/add HTTP/1.1",
 host: "letsclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
2017/04/24 09:47:41 [error] 12139#0: *1 testing "/htdocs/flxx/basic/web" existence failed (13: Permission denied) while logging request, client: 124.42.239.157, server: letsclassifieds.com, request: "GET /info/a
dd HTTP/1.1", host: "letsclassifieds.com", referrer: "https://letsclassifieds.com/info/area-1-122-0/"
```

## Other Information

```
[root@instance-1 basic]# getenforce
Enforcing
[root@instance-1 php-fpm.d]# grep -irnE "user|group" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
4:; Unix user/group of processes
5:; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
8:;user = apache
9:user = www
10:; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
11:group = apache


[root@instance-1 htdocs]# chmod -R 777 /htdocs/flxx/basic/web/assets/
[root@instance-1 htdocs]# ll /htdocs/flxx/basic/web/assets/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx. 2 www root   41 Apr 24 08:18 15e6843e
drwxrwxrwx. 2 www root 4096 Apr 24 08:16 3b2d7f45
drwxrwxrwx. 2 www root   63 Apr 24 08:16 52081253
drwxrwxrwx. 7 www root 4096 Apr 24 08:18 f015baee
drwxrwxrwx. 5 www root   37 Apr 24 08:16 f3c7bc84
[root@instance-1 ~]# grep -irn "user " /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
5:user nginx;
18:    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
[root@instance-1 ~]#
[root@instance-1 ~]# curl -I https://letsclassifieds.com/info/add
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 10:15:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 193
Connection: close

[root@instance-1 ~]#
```

Comment: Is this not clear enough? `The directory is not writable by the Web process: /htdocs/flxx/basic/web/assets`

Comment: I run `chmod -R 777 /htdocs/flxx/basic/web/assets/`,but it still tips 500

Comment: try `chown www-data:www-data . -R` with chmod 777 ?

Comment: it tips `chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’`